# android how to wrap text around a button

Tags: android

Newbie question
I am trying to work out how to wrap text around a button. The button atm has an area down the whole screen..

this is my view - please and thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#3ea155ff"
android:padding="0.1dp"
android:weightSum="1">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgetMood"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.11"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="2"
    android:shadowRadius="3"

    android:text="Inspirational messages that update every 30 mins or click the lovemeditation icon for more.. "
    android:textColor="@android:color/white">
</TextView>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/widgetBtn"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@null"

    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher">

</ImageButton>
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear . Can you add an image what exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: Sorry atm the button is displaying on the right side and it is like a column that my text cannot display in. I want the text to be able to go right across it if it has to as though the button is transparent.

Comment: LOL ... Its `ADM` not `ATM` .haha. and the question still stands unclear . Just add the image what exactly is the need . Graphical arrangement is pretty hard to understand in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `LinearLayout`. In this way each element will take its own portion of space without going to take the place of another.

Try replacing `LinearLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` for instance and set the positions as you want.